# Как изменить тип переменной со string на int через кодировку символов?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно изменить тип переменной string "123" на int 123 через кодировку символов? Или дайте пожалуйста ссылку на мануал, где об этом можно почитать.

Comment: ord() для ASCII или bin2hex() - для UTF-8

Comment: что вы имеете в виду? Нужно перевести строку "123" в число 123 или строку "1" в число 49?

Comment: Нужно перевести строку "123" в число 123

Comment: `$num = intval("123");` Мануал здесь https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Это все понятно. Поступила задача сделать это именно через коровку символов.

Comment: от кого поступила такая задача?

Comment: Ты сам-то понимаешь что значит "через кодировку символов"? Я вот, например, не понимаю.

Comment: Задал преподаватель. Сам не понимаю как это сделать, нагуглить ничего не смог, вот и решил спросить у умных людей.

Comment: функция `ord()` тут вам нужна для решения задачи

Comment: функция ord() только возвращает символьный код первого символа. Как он может помочь решить эту задачку объясните пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь посимвольно функцией `ord` с добавлением смещения:

```php
$str = '123';
$num = 0;
for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; ++$i) {
  $char = $str[$i];  // => "1", "2" или "3"
  $ord = ord($char); // => 48..58 для "0".."9", соответственно
  $dec = $ord - 48;  // => 1, 2 или 3
  $num = $num * 10 + $dec;
}
```

В рузультате этого примера переменная `$num` будет хранить число `123`.

В данном коде:

- `ord` — Конвертирует первый байт строки в число от 0 до 255. [Документация](https://www.php.net/ord).
- `-48` — Смещение кода символа. Символы чисел в таблице символов находятся по порядку (0, 1, ..., 9). Код символа "0" — `48`. Отнимая от кода числового символа получаем само число.
- `$num = $num * 10 + $dec` — сборка числа от большего разряда (слева) к меньшему (вправо). Число смещается на разряд влево умножением на 10 и в новый разряд прибавляется полученное ранее число.

Данный код будет работать корректно если на вход (в переменную `$str`) будут переданы **только числовые символы**. Проверок на иные симолы в этом коде не предусматривается, т.к. это уже не касается вопроса, от того не забудьте их добавить.